# Decaying after 75 days how much left

Tags: calculus

> After $75$ days, a radioactive substance has decayed to $26.7\%$ of its original amount. After an additional $75$ days, what percent of its original amount will it have decayed to?

I got $100-26.7=19.6$, meaning there is $73.3$ from original and multiplied $0.267$ to $73.3$ and got $19.57$. Is this right?

Comment: You should multiply $0.267$ with $0.267$, right? Because at the $75$ day point, the amount is $0.267$ of the original amount, now after another $75$ days, only $26.7\%$ of this will be left, so what is left is finally $0.267 \times 0.267$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon oh tysm

Comment: Ah, good, I was typing to clarify and then you confirm you are doing well! Thanks and good to be of help. By the way, you can up vote answers if you like them, and accept the best answer when you can.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for the info about the site didn't know about it as I am new

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, the 26.7% implies that there is 26.7% of the substance left after the 75 days, meaning a loss of 73.3%. Decaying the substance for another 75 days results in another 73.3% loss (in this case, 73.3% of 26.7), meaning you subtract the result you came up with (19.57%) from the 26.7%, giving you an answer of approximately **7.13**

A simple way is simply taking 26.7% of 26.7% (the resulting amount of substance left after 75 additional days) resulting in the same answer of **7.13**

Comment: ohh tysm it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer with a bit of formalism to complete that of @xav MX.

Let $r$ be the daily rate of decay. That means every day, the substance's radioactivity decays by $r$ compared to the day before. So in $75$ days, it decays by $r^{75}$. By hypothesis, $r^{75}=0.267$.

And in after another $75$ days, it will have decayed by $r^{75+75}=\left(r^{75}\right)^2=0.267^2=0.0713$, which gives $7.13%$ as the answer.

The reason for using some formalism is to be able to generalize to a different period of time. For instance, if they asked you what the decay would be after an additional $100$ days instead of $75$, you'd compute $r^{75+100}=\left(r^{75}\right)^{\frac {175}{75}}=0.267^{\frac {175}{75}}=0.046$ and the answer would be 4.6%.

Comment: Correct, well said and thank you for the additional generalization.